# Building valide: Package libvala-0.12 was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: ubuntu, vala, waf

I am trying to build the latest version of [valide](https://launchpad.net/valide) (0.7.1)

I have successfully built VALA (v 0.17.0) on my machine (Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS). When I run

`./waf configure` in the valide src directory, I get the following output:

```
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for program valac               : /usr/local/bin/valac 
Checking for gobject-2.0                 : yes 
Checking for gthread-2.0                 : yes 
Checking for program version valac >= 0.1.6 : ok 0.17.0 
Checking for program msgfmt                 : /usr/bin/msgfmt 
Checking for program intltool-merge         : /usr/bin/intltool-merge 
Checking for header locale.h                : yes 
Checking for program valadoc                : not found 
Checking for glib-2.0 >= 2.18.0             : yes 
Checking for gio-2.0 >= 2.18.0              : yes 
Checking for gobject-2.0 >= 2.18.0          : yes 
Checking for gmodule-2.0 >= 2.18.0          : yes 
Checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.18.0             : yes 
Checking for libxml-2.0 >= 2.5.0            : yes 
Checking for gtksourceview-2.0 >= 2.10.0    : yes 
Checking for libvala-0.12 >= 0.12.0         : Package libvala-0.12 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libvala-0.12.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libvala-0.12' found 

/path/to/valide-0.7.1/wscript:53: error: the configuration failed (see '/path/to/valide-0.7.1/_build_/config.log')
```

I checked for the relevant .pc files on my system

```
me@yourbox:~/path/to/valide-0.7.1$ find ../vala/ -name 'libvala*.pc' -type f
../vala/vala-0.17.0/libvala-0.18.pc
../vala/vala-0.17.0/libvala.pc
```

I then exported the relevant ENV VAR as follows:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/vala/vala-0.17.0
```

I then run `./waf configure`. To my dismay, I got exactly the same output as posted earlier.

What do I need to fix to build valide on Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

`pkg-config` is looking for `libvala-0.12.pc`. You have `libvala-0.18.pc`. These two files describe different, and presumably incompatible, versions of the libvala API. You need either to port Valide to the new API, or downgrade Vala (0.16 should work.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Regarding your comment: **0.16 should work**. Are you sure about this? (i.e. do you know this for a fact?). I don't want to necessarily downgrade Vala if I end up in the same situation (at least currently, I can compile my VALA code with the latest VALA compiler and emacs/vim

Comment: I don't know it for a fact. My reasoning went like this. You have Vala 0.17 which is the development version leading up to the stable release 0.18. It ships a pkg-config API version 0.18. Developers try not to let that API change too much, so probably the previous stable version, 0.16, is OK. But if you want to be 100% sure, you will have to do some digging in the 0.16 tarballs and see for yourself, or downgrade to 0.12.

Comment: You don't have to downgrade, you can have multiple versions of vala installed in parallel.  Since you're installing 0.12 after 0.18 you may want to pass --disable-unversioned to ./configure, otherwise valac will point to valac-0.12 instead of valac-0.18